# Set width of div(s) equal to wider div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs that are inline and a bigger div below them. Each div has the class `box` and grows with the content in the div.

So, here's what I am trying to achieve:

If the width of the two top div's (including the margin in the middle) is wider than the bottom div, then set the bottoms div's edges to line up with the outfacing sides of the top divs.

If the bottom div is larger then set the top div's outfacing sides to line up with its edges.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box">
           <h1>Transactions</h1>
           <p>as of the date 12/14/2015</p>
           <hr>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Transaction Type</th>
                    <th># Transactions</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Cash</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Check</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Credit</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><b>Total Sales</b></td>
                    <td><b>0</b></td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
           <h1>Monthly Top 10 Product Sales - Dec</h1>
           <p>as of the date 12/14/2015</p>
           <hr>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Qty Sold</th>
                    <th>Total Sales</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 3</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="box">
           <h1>Annual Sales</h1>
           <hr>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Email(s)</th>
                    <th>Merchant ID</th>
                    <th>Gateway ID</th>
                    <th>Bus. Name</th>
                    <th>Devices</th>
                    <th>Transactions</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
table{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 30px !important;
  border: 1px solid #dfe8f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/vLLZgL?editors=011)

Could I do this with just css...or is it necessary to use javascript?

Could probably do something in jQuery like (Not accounting for the margin):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var widthLeft = $("//TopDivLeft").width();
  var widthRight = $("//TopDivRight").width();
  var width = widthLeft + widthRight;

  $("//BottomDiv").css({
    'width': (width + 'px')
  });
});
```

But is it possible to do this in just CSS?

Comment: You could put everything in a div and have the bottom one have width set to the parent div width.

Comment: Yes, I could. But how could I keep the same margin between the top divs and just widen the divs? Instead of doing that and then floating the top divs left and right

Comment: This is definitely doable using tables, or using display: table, display: table-row and display:table-cell will probably work for this case. The first row will have 3 cells. Transactions in the first cell. An empty cell with fixed width in the middle for your margin. Then Monthyl Top 10 in the right cell. Second row, you put a single cell with a column span of 3, and put Annual sales in it. Makes sense?

Comment: Why do you have two slashes (`//`) as the selector? Shouldn't you use the id selector(`#`)?

Comment: Just a comment for the examples sake since I didn't have unique selectors on each.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified your codepen so it uses a table to layout things. Does this work the way you want?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GooEzv

Here is what the html has become:

```
<table>
    <tr class="wrapper">
        <td class="box">
           <h1>Transactions</h1>
           <p>as of the date 12/14/2015</p>
           <hr>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Transaction Type</th>
                    <th># Transactions</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Cash</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Check</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Credit</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><b>Total Sales</b></td>
                    <td><b>0</b></td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
        <td class="margin"></td>
        <td class="box full-width" colspan="3">
           <h1>Monthly Top 10 Product Sales - Dec</h1>
           <p>as of the date 12/14/2015</p>
           <hr>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Qty Sold</th>
                    <th>Total Sales</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 1</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 2</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 3</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Product 4</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="wrapper">
        <td class="box" colspan="3">
           <h1>Annual Sales</h1>
           <hr>
           <table>
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th>Email(s)</th>
                    <th>Merchant ID</th>
                    <th>Gateway ID</th>
                    <th>Bus. Name</th>
                    <th>Devices</th>
                    <th>Transactions</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                 </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>test@xx.com</td>
                    <td>12345</td>
                    <td>54321</td>
                    <td>Test Business</td>
                    <td>Apple</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Thanks! The only thing I would add is an extra empty row before the last table row. `<tr class="margin-height"></tr>` and then `.margin-height { height: 30px;}` just so I can get that margin.

Comment: For the person that downvoted the answer, you could at least explain why you downvoted it.